# Fill class with information from multiple MongoDB collections through Linq left join

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq

I have a problem with LINQ joins in C# on a MongoDB database. Here is the class I want to fill:

```
public class CompanyProduct
{ 
    public string _id { get; set; }
    public string paymentId { get; set; }
    public string productId { get; set; }
    public string date { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

date in this model comes from another class:

```
public class Payment
{
    public string _id { get; set; }
    public string date { get; set; }
}
```

and name and icon from yet another:

```
public class Product
{
    public string _id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

To fill `CompanyProduct` with all the necessary information I could perfrom three different queries on all applicable repositories, but to streamline this process I am trying to integrate them into 1 query. Currently I am on this:

```
public List<CompanyProduct> List(string id)
{
    var productCollection = db.GetCollection<Product>("products");
    var paymentCollection = db.GetCollection<Payment>("payments");

    var query = from c in this.collection.AsQueryable().Where(x => x._id == id)
        join pr in productCollection.AsQueryable() on c.productId equals pr._id into pr
        join pa in paymentCollection.AsQueryable() on c.paymentId equals pa._id into pa
        select new CompanyProduct()
        {
            _id = c._id,
            date = pa.First().date,
            name = pr.First().name,
        };

    return query.ToList()
}
```

Some examples of documents from MongoDB:

CompanyProduct:

[image: CompanyProduct in database]

Payment:

[image: Payment in database]

Product:

[image: Product in database]

However, in this construction `pa.First()` and `pr.First()` always return `null`... I even tried getting rid of the `into pr` and changing `pr.First().name` to `pr.name` but this did not make a difference.

What am I doing wrong here? What improvements do I need to implement?

Comment: Are you sure there is proper data for the join? Meaning are you sure `collection` has records that both `productId` and `paymentId` have matching items in the other tables? Please provide some sample data - an example of content for the `collection` object and the `productCollection` and `paymentCollection` objects

Comment: @GiladGreen Ah that is probably the root indeed. I missed that: the _id is stored as an ObjectId, not a string... Which means I got a whole different problem indeed